# Is there a name for a collection of sets closed under arbitrary union?

Tags: measure-theory, elementary-set-theory, reference-request, soft-question, terminology

A collection of sets closed under finite intersection is (or can be) called a *$\pi$-system*. Is there a name for a collection of sets closed under arbitrary union? That way, a topology can be described verbally in a more succinct way.

Comment: My immediate guess is that the term $\Pi$-system (that's an upper case pi, not lower case) has a dual notion called a $\Sigma$-system ("sigma system"), being closed under finite unions. But again, that's probably _finite_ unions.

Comment: @Arthur, Hi, thanks for that info. My knowing of $\pi$-system was from Billingsley (in the field of probability theory), so I just followed his terminology. What is a field where an uppercase "pi" is more conventional perhaps?

Comment: Back in the day, $\Pi$ was used where we now use $\forall$ and $\Sigma$ was used where we now use $\exists$. It stands to reason that if $\Pi$ is associated with intersections, then $\Sigma$ is analogously associated with unions. But I have no idea whether that's really so, or if this is even the reason that is called a $\Pi$-system (or maybe it really _is_ $\pi$-system).

Comment: See Chapter V: *Complete Lattices* in [**Lattice Theory**](https://www.amazon.com/dp/0821810251) by Garrett Birkhoff, and the google search ["complete lattice" + topology + "closed sets"](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22complete+lattice%22+topology+%22closed+sets%22). (FYI, I'm utterly amazed that a book this well known has no amazon reader reviews!)

Comment: Unionized. . . .